# Wrong selection size when setting logo of Activity and using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am having an issue with the selected color of the logo on the actiobar. As in the screenshot below, the selection doesn't start at the start of the actionbar, and it actually goes beyond the image itself. The image ends 2px after the divider but the selection extends further than that.

I set the icon with android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_menu" in the manifest and I am using ActionBarSherlock. I have checked my custom styles and can't find anything that could cause this. All the sub activities work fine when showing the home icon as up.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Some of my relevant code:

```
protected void actionBarSetup() {
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

  <activity
        android:name="MainActivityWrapper"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_menu"            
        android:label="@string/title_main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>
```

I am also using the SlidingMenu library if that may be related.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen on ICS and up? If so, then it's behaving correctly and not an ABS problem.

Comment: @JakeWharton Yes, seems like this is standard behavior in Android 4.x so I added back the "up" button so it is clear to the user that he can press this icon and the selection looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some part of the code leaves some space here for the "up-arrow" (namely the one painting the selection) whilest another part of the codes doesn't (namely the one drawing the image itself). Can you post the manifest part for the Activity and the onCreate() method too?

Comment: Perhpas explicitly setting `ab.displayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` will help? Otherwise you'd really dig deeper.

Comment: Seems like it only displays "correct" if I include the up arrow so this one looks "unsolveable" without making my own actionbar :-/

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution myself for this.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.NoUp" parent="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This will hide the up indicator and the selection will then work as expected. I then apply this theme only to the activity that has the menu button.

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivityWrapper"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.NoUp"
        android:icon="@drawable/title_icon"
        android:label="@string/live_menu_choice"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>
```